# Chinese Idiom Crossword Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, language, crosswords

Here's a crossword puzzle about Chinese idioms.
[image]

1. Horrible Scream
2. Hundred-year-man
3. Scare-cry nature
4. Big tree wind
5. I'm so sad
6. Ghost and God cry
7. Hit ground and cry to sky
8. Earth good people good
9. Marvellous!
10. Tell you something
11. Reasonable power
12. Talk so much
13. Talk fake things
14. No crops...
15. Besties <3
16. Go back to nature
17. Bamboo in your chest
18. Listen to me!
19. Look front look back
20. Best!
21. Same Same Same
22. Anything to be scared?
23. Sad to happy
24. Find happiness (hehe)

Hint 1:

> 23: 范仲淹

Hint 2:

> 24: Omega Krypton: I HeHe (雙關) every day

PS:

> I will update Cyrus' Adventure soon :)

Comment: NUUUU I FAILED CHINESE EXAM DONT ATTACK ME LIKE THAT I BEG OF YOU

Comment: It's only an exam

Comment: Just add oil next time :)

Comment: You can do it! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combined answers with credits

> 1: 一鳴驚人
>  2: 百年樹人 (Toby Mak)
>  3: 驚天地 泣鬼神 (Toby Mak)
>  4: 樹大招風
>  5: 黯然傷神 (Toby Mak)
>  6: 鬼哭神號 (Toby Mak)
>  7: 號天叩地
>  8: 地靈人傑
>  9: 角立傑出
>  10: 通風報信
>  11: 通權達理
>  12: 口沒遮攔
>  13: 信口雌黃
>  14: 青黃不接
>  15: 青梅竹馬
>  16: 角巾私第
>  17: 胸有成竹 (Toby Mak)
>  18: 馬首是瞻
>  19: 瞻前顧後 (Toby Mak)
>  20: 首屈一指
>  21: 始終如一
>  22: 後顧之憂
>  23: 先憂後樂
>  24: 尋歡作樂

Grid so far:

> [image]

Comment: 7, 8 and 23 are not correct

Comment: Add Oil! @Omega Krypton

Comment: 6 not correct too

Comment: 23 Correct now!

Comment: Yep it is really wrong

Comment: But minor ones lol

Comment: You better change your grid

Comment: Figure out anything?

Comment: nope,any hints pls? @KSharing

Comment: Gave 1 already <3

Answer (score 1):

Just an initial answer (I'm stealing all the easy ones first :)

> 2: 百年樹人 
>  6: 鬼哭神嚎 
>  17: 胸有成竹 
>  19: 瞻前顧後？

Updated after Omega Krypton's answer:

> 3: 驚天地 泣鬼神 
>  5: 黯然傷神 
>  9: 春風和氣？ 
>  9: 通力合作？ 
>  16: 春回大地？ 
>  I have no idea what 24 is..